# No output with basic PowerShell function

Tags: function, powershell

It's already a while since I just started to get along with PowerShell and by today I can say I get many things for my daily tasks done. Everyday is a new day at school though and now, while I was starting to work with functions, I stumble again...
Here is my problem:

Even with the simplest function taken from many beginner's tutorials it is not working on my work PC nor on my home PC nor on my work's admin servers.

For instance:

```
function MyDate {
    Get-Date
}
```

Saved the PS1 file with the name MyDate.ps1 to a local folder and just run this tiny little thing from the PowerShell prompt like that

```
PS C:\PS> C:\PS\MyDate.ps1
```

That's how it was exactly explained in a PS-Functions-for-Dummies tutorial.
Just in the tutorial the output should show the date. In my siutation there is just nothing. No error, no red-PS-specific information, nothing!
If I use the function within my full script like that:

```
function MyDate {
    Get-Date
}
MyDate

PS C:\PS> C:\PS\MyDate.ps1

Montag, 1. Oktober 2018 19:28:32
```

Well, then I get the date output.
Wondering why not directly from the prompt without calling the function within the script, as functions are supposed to be used?
And again, in many of these pretty simple examples it is supposed to work..
Where am I wrong then?

---

**Edit:** Not sure if this is now the right policy to add more updates to a question?

I will probably share a more specific example of my scripts and how I want to "transform" it into a function. Short example would be:

```
$myServers = Get-Content D:\Servers\Windows2016.txt
foreach ($myServer in $myServers) {
    Get-Printer -ComputerName $myServer |
        Where-Object {$_.DeviceType -eq "Printer"} |
        Select Name, PortName
}
```

For other support teams it has to be as simple as possible. So my idea was to "wrap" a function around these few lines, so that another person would execute it like this

```
C:\Scripts\Our-Printers -File D:\Servers\Windows2016.txt
```

`Our-Printers` would then be my function name of course.

I tried that already but discarded the stuff though as it did not work in first try, that's why I wanted to start with pretty basic stuff and at the moment it seems that I don't get it. But by the way, within a script my functions worked already, just they are not made to require input in that way of the example. Which means I defined functions in a large script and with that I am able to change orders or even skip certain functions based on user input...

Comment: Edits to clarify a question are encouraged as long as the update doesn't invalidate answers that were already given or change the desired result to something different than what was originally stated. In case of the latter it's better to post a new question and reference the previous one there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a function in a script means you write a block of code that can be invoked via a symbolic name. The function is not automatically invoked by running the script, though. You still need to actually do that.

```
PS C:\> Get-Content .\a.ps1
function GetDate {
    Get-Date
}
PS C:\> .\a.ps1
PS C:\> Get-Content .\b.ps1
function GetDate {
    Get-Date
}
GetDate                  # ← actually invoke the function
PS C:\> .\b.ps1

Montag, 1. Oktober 2018 19:50:32
```

Only (script-)global scope code in a script is executed automatically when the script is invoked.

Depending on the purpose of your script this may or may not be what you want. For instance, if you intend to just run the script from some external script or command to have it do something it makes sense to automatically invoke the function when the script is executed. If on the other hand you intend to use the script as a kind of library, storing different functions that you want to be able to invoke separately, you'd omit function invocations from the script. Then you can dot-source the script [as Mathias described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52596205/1630171) and invoke the function(s) you need.

```
PS C:\> Get-Content .\a.ps1
function GetDate {
    Get-Date
}
PS C:\> . .\a.ps1    # ← load the function definition into the current scope
PS C:\> GetDate      # ← actually invoke the function

Montag, 1. Oktober 2018 19:50:32
```

---

**Edit:** Your ultimate goal could be achieved either way. There are files  (called [profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)) that PowerShell sources automatically when launched. You could define a function and put that in the appropriate profile (per user or system-wide). After restarting PowerShell people will then be able to invoke the function.

Alternatively you could put the code in a script (without wrapping it in a function), and put that script someplace where the intended users can execute it.

Which of these two approaches is preferable for your situation depends on a number of factors. Do you have an domain or a workgroup? In case of a domain, can you make changes to the AD? Do you have a shared location where you could put files? Do you have a software deployment system? And so on.

Another important question is: will the users invoke the code just from PowerShell or also from elsewhere (e.g. CMD). In case of the latter one would normally prefer a script over a function in a profile.

Either way you'd [parametrize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-3.0) your script or function like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$File
)

$myServers = Get-Content $File
foreach ($myServer in $myServers) {
    Get-Printer -ComputerName $myServer |
        Where-Object {$_.DeviceType -eq "Printer"} |
        Select-Object Name, PortName
}
```

The parameter definition belongs at the beginning of the script or function respectively.

Add [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458353), so that people can run `Get-Help Our-Printers` or `Our-Printers -?` to see how they're supposed to use it, e.g.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
List printers.

.DESCRIPTION
List printers. The computers to check are read from a file.

.PARAMETER File
A file with a list of computer names (one per line).
#>
```

Use [parameter validation](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/04/using-powershell-parameter-validation-to-make-your-day-easier/) for enforcing valid input, e.g.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_})]
    [string]$File
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not get it on first look, but now it am starting to understand. Just then I don't understand these tutorials, as they were never mentioning these approach.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a function definition in a script file, and you want to "import" that function, you need to use the dot source (`.`) operator:

```
PS C:\PS> . C:\PS\MyDate.ps1
PS C:\PS> MyDate
Montag, 1. Oktober 2018 19:39:18
```

---

The difference between using the `.` operator and just calling the script by name, is that the `.` operator runs the script in the calling scope - meaning that the function definition persists in your powershell session after the script stops executing.

You can read more about scopes in the [`about_Scopes` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#using-dot-source-notation-with-scope)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Tryed to run the script then with  

. C:\PS\MyDate.ps1

but there is still no output.
Also in none of the tutorials it was mentioned to be required.
I read a bit around scopes now and basically I have now issues using my scripts from the console.
Just additionally, none of the given examples works for me. I'm not getting any errors but the functions just don't function [link] >> Example page (https://www.faqforge.com/powershell/create-function-powershell/)

Comment: @Obsolet well, running the script containing the function definition by itself _is not supposed to do anything_! Defining a function and executing a function are two distinct actions

Comment: I just wanted to start small before I go big. I wrote scripts for automated application intallations and even more, like regular server checkes etc. and I wanted to make things easier for other teams using them by simply creating the script as a function and allow to pass a server name or a path to a file of a server list for instance, that it would be like My-ServerCheck D:\Servers\Windows2016.txt. Instead of prompting or even editing the lines within the script. When I followed the trainings, it was shown to work with these mini stuff right away. I know example is usless

Comment: just another example: this should work too: `code`function hello-world 
{ 
write-host "hello world" 
}

Comment: I think I am getting closer a bit, not meaning I understand yet completely ;) I was now able to use the way with the "." and then I typed just Mydate and it gave me the right output. Perhaps I am getting to the point....maybe :)